# Normal distribution of

Tags: probability, statistics

> In a given grocery store, apples have an average weight of $194$g and standard deviation of $40$g. Suppose that their weights are independent and follow a normal distribution.

If a customer requests $1$ kg of apples and given that the employer chooses randomly each apple and continues until the total weight is the intended one; calculate the probability of being necessary exactly $6$ apples $(1kg=1000g)$.

Each apple's weight is a random variable $X \sim N(194,40^2)$; and defining $S_n = X_1+\dots+ X_n$;I should calculate $P(S_5<1000\leq S_6)$; where $X_i \sim N(194,40^2); i=1, \dots,6$; but how could I compute this probability?

Comment: Please provide a reference for the original source of the problem (or any material originally written by others): https://math.stackexchange.com/help/referencing